# JSON array as a single parameter value in Python's requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm learning to work with requests and JSON, so I decided to use API of the app I heavily use. I've successfully made requests to receive an auth code and access token, so I can get the content with the request like this:

```
requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get',
               data = {'consumer_key' : consumer_key,
                       'access_token' : access_token,
                         'detailType' : 'simple',
                              'count' : '50'})
```

But when I want to modify entries, I build the similar request, which doesn't work for some reason:

```
requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/send',
               data = {'consumer_key' : consumer_key,
                       'access_token' : access_token,
                            'actions' : [{'item_id':'1000000000','action':'archive'}]})
```

The [API guide](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/modify#action_archive) suggests the following valid example (I decoded it for visibility):

```
https://getpocket.com/v3/send?actions=[{"action":"archive","time":1348853312,"item_id":229279689}]&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY
```

I get the error "400 Bad Request" and one of the headers says: "Invalid request, please refer to API documentation".

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: Oh, right, updated the post.

Comment: The `data` argument does not JSON-encode a Python dictionary; you need the `json` argument for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `requests` library. From version 2.4.2 onwards, you can use `json` as parameter. It should have better json encoding than `data`.

```
requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/send', json={
    'consumer_key': consumer_key,
    'access_token': access_token,
    'actions': [{
        'item_id':'1000000000',
        'action':'archive'
     }]
})
```

See here for more information: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

EDIT: If only `action` key should be a json string, you can try following:

```
import simplejson as json

requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/send', data={
        'consumer_key': consumer_key,
        'access_token': access_token,
        'actions': json.dumps([{
            'item_id':'1000000000',
            'action':'archive'
         }])
    })
```

I would recommend `simplejson` over `json` package as it is updated more frequently.

Comment: It appears that only one of the three URL parameters is actually intended to be a JSON string.

Comment: @chepner didn't notice that. I'll edit my comment to reflect that.

Comment: It just did work! I simply copied and pasted both snippets, both are good with even both GET and POST. I think the problem was the json encoding, and I was close to the solution as @chepner suggested, but I missed that he missed brackets for the actions list.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

From your example:

```
https://getpocket.com/v3/send?\
  actions=[{"action":"archive","time":1348853312,"item_id":229279689}]&\
  access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&\
  consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY
```

we see there are three URL-encoded parameters, only *one* of which (`actions`) is a JSON value. You need to use something like

```
actions = {
    "action": "archive",
    "time": "1348853312",
    "item_id": "229279689"
}
requests.post("https://getpocket.com/v3/send",
              data={
                  "actions": json.dumps(actions),
                  "access_token": access_token,
                  "consumer_key": consumer_key
              })
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I get 500 Internal Server Error, I also tried to perform urlencode the data after crafting the actions dict, but didn't succeed.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it appears `item_id` and `time` both need to be JSON strings, not numbers.

Comment: We were close, please check the @BluePat solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the API requires the parameters to be on the URL, but you're sending on the post body.

You should encode you dictionary into the URL:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = {
        'consumer_key' : consumer_key,
        'access_token' : access_token,
        'actions' : [{'item_id':'1000000000','action':'archive'
       }
requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/send/?' + urlencode(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I kept in mind that POST-only requirement was API-wide, but it turns out was just Auth-wide.

Comment: It's quite odd the way this API works, because the `/get/` endpoint has a very different behavior.

Anyway, it worked for you ?

Comment: After changing POST to GET, I got the error about missing API key, which might mean the encoding issue. Finally, with the encoding the way you suggested I get the needed URL (my IDE shows the URL used that is almost exactly what was the example). But I still get the error. I'm confused with the Pocket's example - it shows the key and token are in square brackets...